# How to manually remove a directory from svn?

Tags: svn

I already deleted the directory with RVM's `rm` command. How can I remove it from the svn cache too?

Answer (score 6):

You are maintaining a separate repository of code changes in SVN, in addition to your working directory. You have to use SVN to manage changes so its idea of your source is accurate. For good or bad, that means you have to let it control things.

When you deleted the directory, you didn't tell SVN to do it, so its copy of the directory still exists, and any subsequent `svn update` or `svn checkout` will restore that directory.

Normally you should do `svn rm directory`, where "directory" is the name of the directory you want to remove, to get rid of it. Because you removed the directory first you'll need to make SVN happy by doing a `svn update` to restore the directory on your disk, then do the `svn rm directory`.

So, your commands are:

```
svn update
svn rm directory
svn commit .
```

The last line, `svn commit .` will update your SVN repo to tell it to delete the directory too, which will remove it from the "svn cache".

Answer (score 0):

you must do 'svn delete' first and then issue an 'svn commit'.